# An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

This code is in the ScheduledTaskAgent.cs and ofcourse runs in the background.

I always get this exception at the statement   : stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 The image is in my project files under the root.I tried with "Do Not Copy" and "Always Copy".But still the same error comes.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
             { 
                 BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\DefaultImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                 img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                 img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
                 {
                     WriteableBitmap wbitmap = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
                     TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();                       
                     textBlock.Text = "Sample Text";
                     textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                     wbitmap.Render(textBlock, new TranslateTransform() { X = 25, Y = 10 }); ;
                     wbitmap.Invalidate();

                     using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                     {                    
                         wbitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wbitmap.PixelWidth, wbitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                         stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                         SaveToIsolatedStorage(stream);
                         stream.Close();
                     }
                 };
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the SaveJpeg method closes the stream and you cannot seek in it afterwards. Try this:

```cs
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile(fileName))
{
    wbitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wbitmap.PixelWidth, wbitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
}
```